Get cpython to optimize out constant conditions
I'm writing code in Python that needs to run as efficiently as possible, but I sometimes have the need to dig deep into debugging statements. Instead of commenting these in- or out (or using an external preprocessor for code like it was suggested here Python equivalent for #ifdef DEBUG or here How do you implement "#ifdef" in python?) I would like to define a variable at the start of my module
_verbose_debugging = False

That I can easily change from False to True if I need it to. Then, my logging code looks like this:
if _verbose_debugging:
    print("something resource intensive")

However, what I want is that if it set to "False" that the debugging is entirely omitted in the generated bytecode similar to how __debug__ functions. I do not want to use __debug__, however, since it's on by default and will cause other conflicts.
Is there a way to tell the CPython bytecode compiler that my variable _verbose_debugging will never change during the runtime of the interpreter and it can safely optimize it out if it has seen False there once?
I read many Stackoverflow articles and looked into the internal behavior of __debug__ (which unfortunately seems to be "magic").

If you want to use assert for debugging, this might help. In short, running python with the -O flag will ignore assert statements

"tell the CPython bytecode compiler that my variable _verbose_debugging will never change" AFAIK no. CPython is an interpreter so nothing is much optimized and this is actually hard to do since the language is very dynamic. I see two options. The first is to generate the code based on the checks (generally not great), and the second is to use a general-purpose Python JIT like PyPy (ie. not to use CPython). Cython might help too in this case (still compatible with CPython) since it compiles the Python code to a native C one (and C compilers do such an optimization for global constants).

I do not think that smth like if _verbose_debugging: actually consume a lot of time. This is comparison with single binary variable, the easiest possible if condition. So if your question is I want to have the most efficient code as possible you need to optimize other code parts or switch to more efficient languages like C++ or Rust.
